# jquery, marquee timer stop / go

Tags: jquery, html, marquee

```
$('marquee').marquee('pointer').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).trigger('stop');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).trigger('start');
    }).mousemove(function (event) {
        if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
            this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
        }
    }).mousedown(function (event) {
        $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
    }).mouseup(function () {
        $(this).data('drag', false);
    });
```

Anyone know the best way for this to stop maybe on a timer after 3 seconds, pause for 3 seconds and then continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Link to `$(...).marquee(...)` please?

Comment: [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/marquee) to marquee

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`this.stop();` or `this.start()`

Comment: Do you know how i would code that into the current function using a timer?